# jQuery No Conflict mode doesn't work

Tags: jquery, mootools, conflict

On my page http://all-fours.pl/ I'm using moo.fx for.. something, I don't really know what. And now I was trying to add a jquery banner rotator. But still regarding fact that I'm setting my banner script in jQuery.noConflict(), the moo.fx library gives errors :

function to set the [jquery cycle plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.banner').cycle({
        effect: 'fade'
    });
});
</script>
```

Now my firebug states, that "$ is not a function" in some moo.fx script. How to resolve this ?

Comment: You'll need to post the order of your `<script>` includes here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone finds this later [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) is intended to [restore](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L350) `$` to it's [previous value](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L13), if you include jQuery first that previous value is `undefined`.  You'll need to include jQuery *after* what you want to restore it to in order for it to work.

The [`jQuery.noConflict()` documentation has more details](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by including jquery at the bottom of my scripts list.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `$` inside the function parameters:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.banner').cycle({
        effect: 'fade'
    });
});
</script>
```